# Apache Beam – issue with Deduplicate function

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have an issue with `apache_beam.transforms.deduplicate.Deduplicate` transformation. Please, look on a code sample below:

```
    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            # | 'Load' >> beam.Create(['a', 'b', 'b']) ## <- works fine
            | 'Load' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('./input.txt'). ## <- breaks Dedup
            | 'Dedup' >> Deduplicate(processing_time_duration=1000).with_input_types(AnyStr)
            | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

If I create collection manually – everything works fine and as expected. But when I try to load something from disk (text file, Avro files, etc.) Deduplicate stops working and throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py", line 370, in call
    self.attempt_call(
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py", line 404, in attempt_call
    evaluator.start_bundle()
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 867, in start_bundle
    self.runner.start()
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1475, in start
    self._invoke_bundle_method(self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_start_bundle)
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1460, in _invoke_bundle_method
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1507, in _reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1458, in _invoke_bundle_method
    bundle_method()
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 559, in invoke_start_bundle
    self.signature.start_bundle_method.method_value())
  File "/Users/ds/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/sdf_direct_runner.py", line 122, in start_bundle
    self._invoker = DoFnInvoker.create_invoker(
TypeError: create_invoker() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_processor' [while running 'Load/Read/SDFBoundedSourceReader/ParDo(SDFBoundedSourceDoFn)/pair']
```

This happens only with `Deduplicate` and `DeduplicatePerKey` transformations. All other things like `ParDo`, `Map`, etc. work fine.

- Python version: 3.9.14
- Apache Beam: 2.41.0
- Platform: Apple's M1 ARM

Comment: How do you configure you `input.txt` file ? Can you share with us the content of `input.txt` file please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun it's just several lines of text. In my case it's just numbers: 1 2 2 3 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help.

Indeed I tested your code and it doesn't works, maybe I am wrong but I think the `Deduplicate` `PTransform` seems to be more adapted for jobs with windowing logics (processing time and event time).

It works with `beam.Create` (even if it's a bounded source) but not with `ReadFromText` because a type is not inferred :

```
E     TypeError: create_invoker() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_processor'
```

I propose you another solution that works in your case, and it's more adapted to deduplicate data in `batch` job and `bounded` source :

```py
    def test_dedup(self):
        with TestPipeline() as p:
            (
                    p
                    # | 'Load' >> beam.Create(['a', 'b', 'b'])  ## <- works fine
                    | 'Load' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(
                f'{ROOT_DIR}/input.txt')  ## <- breaks D
                    # | 'Dedup' >> Deduplicate(processing_time_duration=1000).with_input_types(AnyStr)
                    | 'Group by' >> beam.GroupBy(lambda el: el)
                    | 'Get key' >> beam.Map(lambda t: t[0])
                    | 'Print' >> beam.Map(self.print_el)
            )
```

The input.txt content is :

```
1
2
2
3
4
```

The output `PCollections` is :

```
1
2
3
4
```

I used `GroupBy` on the current element, it gives me a `Tuple` => 2 -> [2, 2]
and then I added a `map` on the deduplicated key on the `Tuple`.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Could you please explain regarding type inference in my original example? I've added with_input_types(), so as far as I can understand, Deduce function should have type information.

Comment: You're welcome, I also tested with `with_input_types` and other functions, I don't understand why but it didn't worked.